# How do I set the content encoding on a HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, encoding, httpresponse

I want to set the Content-Encoding on a HttpResponseMessage and I can't for the life of me find out how.  Given this WebApi action

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    byte[] tile = GetTile();

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {Content = new ByteArrayContent(tile)};

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf");

    return result;
}
```

How do I set the Content-Encoding on the header to gzip?

```
 result.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding
```

is read only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ContentEncoding` property is an instance of [ICollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.118).aspx).

This provides **`.Add()`** and **`.Clear()`** methods for controlling the contents.

Answer (score 6):

Not to detract from richzilla's answer which is of course totally correct and answered my question. Seeing as this is getting a few votes and visits there must be other people making the same mistake I did so it's worth saying the complete answer to my problem was

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");
```

Comment: Might, depending on browser,not work if there already is another encoding type present.  The second one that you add could be ignored.

Comment: ... in which case, do a Clear() before you Add() it.